# FTP multiple file in different folders by perl

Tags: perl, ftp

I'm trying for an ftp script, that sends files in different directory within the same connection, the below script is to FTP files from only one folder.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::FTP;
use Cwd;

my $server    = "HOST_NAME"
my $username  = "USERNAME";
my $pass      = "PASSWORD";
my $ftp;

$ftp = Net::FTP->new( $server, Debug => 1 ) or die $@;

$ftp->login( $username, $pass ) or die $ftp->login failed;

my @transferFileList = glob "Filename*.log";

$ftp->cwd('somefolder') or die $ftp->message;
$ftp->binary();

for (@transferFileList){

      $ftp->put(cwd . "\\$_") or die $ftp->message;
}

$ftp->quit or die $ftp->message;
```

Comment: *that sends files in different directory within the same connection,* - with FTP each new file transfer is a new TCP connection. You probably mean the same FTP session or "*initiated* from within the same control connection". But is not clear what you actual problem is - don't you know how to change folders within Perl? So please show what you actually tried to solve the problem and where your actual problem is.

Comment: I'm trying from same FTP session

Comment: Okay, but you haven't explained what the problem is. Please give us some examples. (By the way, I've removed the second question that you tacked on at the end because it's nothing to do with the rest of your post and needs to be asked separately.)

Comment: I'm trying to FTP files from two different directories.. I'm not sure where to add the 2nd directory details in the script..

Comment: You don't need `$ftp->put(cwd . "\\$_")` because the path is only necessary to help the method call to find the file. Since it's in the current working directory, just `$ftp->put($_)` is fine.

Comment: @RyanEdwards: You can change the remote directory with `$ftp->cwd`. You can change the local directory with `chdir`. Or you could use `$ftp->put($local_name,$remote_name)`.That should be all you need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'll write an answer, as this seems to be the only way to interpret your question, although it seems that you already know how to use `$ftp->cwd`

There are two ways.

- You can use `$ftp->cwd('someotherfolder')` before each transfer to change where the file is stored

  Remember that if you use a relative path each time then you will be diving ever deeper into the server's file structure. You may want to use `$ftp->cwd('../someotherfolder')` to go up a level and back down to a sister folder on the same level as the previous one, or you can just use an absolute path like `$ftp->cwd('/pub/someotherfolder')` which cannot be misinterpreted
- You can pass a second parameter to `$ftp->put`, which specifies the path and filename for the remote file that is created

  If you choose this option then no calls to `$ftp->cwd` are necessary

If the directories where you want to store the files may not exist then you will need to use `$ftp->mkdir('newfolder')` before transferring there

Since the method of changing the (remote) working directory is fairly straightforward, here's some code that demonstrates the second option. It supposes that you want to put each of your log files into a new folder, called `/pub/dir01`, `/pub/dir02` etc.

```
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new( $server, Debug => 1 ) or die $@;
$ftp->login( $username, $pass ) or die $ftp->message;
$ftp->binary();

my $dir = 'dir01';

for my $file ( glob 'Filename*.log' ) {

    my $abs_dir = '/pub/' . $dir++;

    $ftp->mkdir($abs_dir);

    $ftp->put($file, "$abs_dir/$file") or die $ftp->message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your folder is under root folder:

```
$ftp->cwd("test");
```

If your folder is under `root\test` folder:

```
$ftp->cwd("test\test1");
```

Comment: Does this code really work like that, with a single backslack?